# Showing Progressdialog in asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an async task for getting result from web services. I my class I've tried to show and hide a progress dialog. but in the middle of getting the result from web services some error occur as you can see in log cat. I think the problem is that I'm trying to get the result in async mode and then finishing current activity. since my async task is getting my activity in the constructor and using that for showing ProgressDialog, after finishing the activity and trying to show another progress dialog in async task this problem occurred. What should I do?

```
public class AsyncCallWs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    public String methodName="";
    private WebService ws;
    private ArrayList<ServiceParam> paramsList;
    private boolean hasParams; 
    private Activity activity;
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;

    public AsyncCallWs(Activity activity,OnTaskCompleted listener,String methodName) {
        xLog.position();
        try {
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.activity = activity;
            hasParams = false;
            this.listener = listener;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            xLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public AsyncCallWs(Activity activity,OnTaskCompleted listener,String methodName,ArrayList<ServiceParam> params) {
        xLog.position();
        try {
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.activity = activity;
            this.paramsList = params;
            hasParams = true;
            this.listener = listener;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            xLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do something...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        xLog.position();

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        listener.onTaskCompleted(result,methodName);
        xLog.info("Output of current AsyncTask is:"+ result);

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772): Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fc05a0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fc05a0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPreExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:85)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Sync.doSync(Sync.java:307)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Login.clickHandler(Login.java:70)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-11 08:08:58.808: E/WindowManager(26772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772): Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fef4a8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fef4a8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPreExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:85)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Sync.doSync(Sync.java:311)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Login.clickHandler(Login.java:70)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-11 08:08:58.837: E/WindowManager(26772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772): Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fb88b0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fb88b0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPreExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:85)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Sync.doSync(Sync.java:316)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Login.clickHandler(Login.java:70)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-11 08:08:58.867: E/WindowManager(26772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772): Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4102c668 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4102c668 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPreExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:85)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Sync.doSync(Sync.java:320)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Login.clickHandler(Login.java:70)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-11 08:08:58.878: E/WindowManager(26772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772): Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4103cd98 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shareholders.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4103cd98 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-168,114} that was originally added here
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPreExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:85)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Sync.doSync(Sync.java:325)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.example.shareholders.Login.clickHandler(Login.java:70)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-11 08:08:58.898: E/WindowManager(26772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


12-11 08:08:59.118: D/AndroidRuntime(26772): Shutting down VM
12-11 08:08:59.138: W/dalvikvm(26772): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:383)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:285)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:323)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:306)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPostExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:113)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at ClassLibrary.AsyncCallWs.onPostExecute(AsyncCallWs.java:1)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-11 08:08:59.167: E/AndroidRuntime(26772):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which context you are passing as first parameter to AsyncCallWs method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `this.dialog.dismiss();` before you finish your `Activity`

Comment: The dialog is not in my activity, It's in async task class and this.dialog is not recognized.

Comment: Then create a method that dismisses the `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncCallWs` and call it in your `Activity` before finishing it

Comment: there is 10 instances of my Async task class. how to find that all of them are finished?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a headless fragment and do your async processing inside that instead of inside the activity.

There is a tutorial here:
http://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/android-headless-fragment/